# Overture Maps , how to query using DuckDB

Tags: maps, duckdb

I need to use Overture Maps, which are available at https://overturemaps.org/, to get latitude and longitude data for a specific address.
I am using DuckDB to read Parquet files. What query should I write to obtain the correct information?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are blog posts / tutorials discussing this task, e.g. https://til.simonwillison.net/overture-maps/overture-maps-parquet.